# How to assign a background color to an arbitrary command?

Tags: color, sphinx

When using custom roles, Sphinx will generate a LaTeX that looks like this

```
\sphinxAtStartPar
\DUrole{customroleone}{This is under custom role 1}

\sphinxAtStartPar
\DUrole{customroletwo}{This is under custom role 2}
```

I would like the background of `This is under custom role 1` to be red and `This is under custom role 2` to be green.

I could achieve this behaviour using environments, but this creates a newline after the content, and I would like the color change to be inline.

I tried setting this in the preamble, but it did not change the color

```
% Added hunk
\newcommand{customroleone}{
    \small
    \color{green}
}

% Deleted hunk
\newcommand{customroletwo}{
    \small
    \color{red}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your requirement is not clear for me, I guess you are looking for `\colorbox{red}{...text...}`

Comment: The thing is, the first snippet is generated as-is by Sphinx, and I cannot really change it. I can only add a preamble to the overall document. Apparently there is some way to trick LaTeX into putting a style for those classes [using macros](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/user/latex.html#classes) but I really can't get there ..

Comment: try with `\newcommand{\DUrolecustomroleone}{\small\leavevmode\color{green}}` (and be careful with linebreaks and space, they matter).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer good catch, I did not know that `\newcommand` would expect the concatenation of `\DUrole` and whatever was in curly braces afterwards. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
\newcommand{\DUrolecustomroleone}{\small\leavevmode\color{green}}
```

And be careful with linebreaks and spaces, they matter.

Comment: I also had to include `#1`, to wrap the text in color without affecting surrounding text : `\newcommand{\DUrolecustomroleone}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}`